# O que significa o retorno do banco INSERT 0 1?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

Quando realizo comandos no banco tenho retornos para e execução dos mesmo.

#### Duvida

- O que significa o `0` em `INSERT 0 1`?

#### Exemplo

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    id SERIAL,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

input : `INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('Guilherme');`
output : `INSERT 0 1`

input : `INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('Guilherme'), ('Felipe'), ('Carlos');`
output : `INSERT 0 3`

O segundo parâmetro já notei que se trata de `rows` efetivamente inseridas.

#### Adendo

O mesmo não existe quando se trate de `UPDATE`

input : `UPDATE test SET name = 'guilherme' WHERE name = 'Guilherme'`
output : `UPDATE 1`

Comment: Encontrei uma explicação aqui no [fórum do Postgre](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4AD5F063.8050708@iol.ie) que pode ser útil @Guilherme! Em tradução diz o seguinte: Versões mais recentes
Do PostgreSQL, por padrão, têm tabelas criadas sem `OIDs` nas linhas, então você apenas obtém um `0` retornado em vez disso.

Comment: @Everson não, ate pesquisei sobre, mas não me aprofundei para disser que sei.

Comment: Se vc mandar um valor duplicado nesse insert, a saida é: 1068, 0?

Comment: @rray não, continua sendo `INSERT 0 1`;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extraído da [página no manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) :

**Saídas**

Na conclusão bem-sucedida de um comando **INSERT** ele retorna uma marca de comando do formulário:

> INSERT [oid] [count]

A contagem [count] é o número de linhas inseridas. Se a contagem [count] é exatamente **UMA** e a tabela de destino possui OIDs habilitado, o OID é atribuído à linha inserida. Caso contrário OID é zero.

[OIDs](http://pgdocptbr.sourceforge.net/pg80/datatype-oid.html) são utilizados internamente pelo PostgreSQL como chaves primárias em várias tabelas do sistema. Seria quase a mesma coisa que [ROWID](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) do Oracle.

**Exemplificando:**

OID irá aparecer somente se você INSERIR uma LINHA. Pois o retorno é singular (single return), por isso é mostrado 0 para inserção de muitos registros, mas por trás é gerado o OID para cada registro inserido na tabela. (a menos que seja especificado WITHOUT OIDS na criação da tabela, ou que a variável de configuração default_with_oids esteja definida como falso.)

**Executando alguns INSERT's:**

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('x', 'x', 'x');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('x', 'x', 'y');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('x', 'y', 'x');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('x', 'x', 'y');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('x', 'x', 'y');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('x', 'y', 'y');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('y', 'y', 'y'); 
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('y', 'y', 'y');

SELECT oid, t.* FROM t;

  oid  | c1 | c2 | c3
-------+----+----+----
 17839 | x  | x  | x
 17840 | x  | x  | y
 17841 | x  | y  | x
 17842 | x  | x  | y
 17843 | x  | x  | y
 17844 | x  | y  | y
 17845 | y  | y  | y
 17846 | y  | y  | y
(8 linhas)
```

Cada registro é atribuído um `OID` diferente, pois internamente cada registro (linha) é um objeto diferente.

```
DELETE FROM t WHERE oid NOT IN
(SELECT min(oid) FROM t GROUP BY c1, c2, c3);
DELETE 3

SELECT oid, t.* FROM t;

  oid  | c1 | c2 | c3
-------+----+----+----
 17839 | x  | x  | x
 17840 | x  | x  | y
 17841 | x  | y  | x
 17844 | x  | y  | y
 17845 | y  | y  | y
```

Comment: +1, mas ainda tenho algumas duvidas, Esse OID sera sempre `0`? em que situação ele muda? caso venha algo nele, para que pode ser usado?

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert verifique se ficou mais entendível

Answer (score 0):

O primeiro número significa que a tabela foi criada sem OIDs (configuração padrão do PostgreSQL). O segundo número significa o número de registros adicionados.

Os OIDs basicamente fornecem um ID interno, globalmente exclusivo para cada linha, contido em uma coluna do sistema.